# bool must take exactly one argument == operator implementation file

Tags: c++

I have a header file where I am declaring a bool operator as a public member of the function RewardCard

```
        bool operator ==(const RewardCard& card1, const RewardCard& card2);
```

I have moved all implementation details of the class I am defining into a separate file rewards.cpp which includes the headerfile

I have defined the bool operator as follows:

```
bool RewardCard::operator ==(const RewardCard& card1, const RewardCard& card2)
{
   return(card1.name == card2.name && card1.id == card2.id && card1.store == card2.store)
}
```

When compiling the program I am getting an error that says this function must take exactly one argument.

I am avoiding a friend function for overloading as I know these can be achieved using a member function.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When compiling the program I am getting an error that says this function must take exactly one argument. [...] What am I doing incorrectly?

Your compiler is telling you *exactly* what you're doing wrong. You are writing `operator==` as a member function taking the wrong number of arguments. It must take exactly one.

You are comparing the implicit `this` object to the other object, so your code should be:

```
bool RewardCard::operator ==(const RewardCard& rhs)
{
   return name == rhs.name && id == rhs.id && store == rhs.store;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Makes perfect sense.